# Repetir cabeçalho na impressão

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, vb.net

Não posso divulgar o relatório que estou utilizando, por isso, peguei um modelo genérico no google para me ajudar a explicar a dúvida.

Supondo que o meu relatório é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo é montado via HTML em um sistema que trabalha tanto com C# quanto com VB.Net. A minha intenção é em cada página de impressão, manter o seguinte cabeçalho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse cabeçalho é uma imagem no corpo HTML, aliás, todo o relatório é feito simplesmente com HTML e CSS a base dos dados que recebe do banco de dados, ou seja, não está sendo utilizado nenhum componente como por exemplo, Crystal Reports.

Como posso proceder para manter esse cabeçalho em cada página da impressão?

Comment: Como você faz para converter do HTML para o PDF?

Comment: Na verdade, não estou. Criei um botão com `onclick="window.print()"` e configurei o estilo via CSS. Atualmente ele trás a impressão de forma perfeita, apenas não repete o cabeçalho pois não está dentro de uma `<thead>`.

Comment: Acho que não dá pra fazer sem usar uma ferramenta. O HTML não possui cabeçalho e rodapé por definição.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Qual solução simples você me indicaria? Tenho que implementar em um dia, por isso houve esse desenvolvimento 'meia boca'

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa, poe isso dentro de uma tabela `<table>` e utiliza o titulo dentro do `<thead>` isso pelo que eu conheço só irá funcionar no Firefox (sei que no Chrome e no Opera não funciona), é uma solução rápida, mas "meia boca". Hehe

Comment: @Fernando hahaha é uma solução. O problema é que no meu relatório, tenho dois elementos `<table>`. Se eu possuísse apenas 1, poderia fazer isso sem erro

Comment: Você pode tentar pelo VReport. Com ele você consegue configurar o que deseja, delimitando por div's. Segue um tutorial http://www.maujor.com/blog/2009/09/06/extensao-vreport/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível realizar isso sem a ajuda de uma ferramenta. [O HTML Renderer para PdfSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp) é um envelope para o PdfSharp, e o PdfSharp possui o recurso de cabelho e rodapé.

Se tudo o mais falhar, você ainda [pode usar o PdfSharp puro](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/invoice-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Answer (score 3):

Nada muito além do meu comentário, e com pouco suporte dos Browsers (hoje funciona no Firefox e IE (não sei se em todos)), você poderia colocar seu conteúdo dentro de uma tabela e adicionar o titulo (ou cabeçalho) que deseja repetir dentro do elemento `<thead>`, isso faria com que no momento da impressão (nos Browsers citados) os cabeçalhos de repetissem a cada pagina. Algo similar a isso:

```
<table>    
  <thead>
     <!-- Will print at the top of every page -->
  </thead>    
  <tbody>
     <!-- Page content -->
  </tbody>   
</table>
```

Mas como você citou já há outra tabelas em sua pagina, então você poderia apenas aplicar o estilo de tabela a seus elementos, algo assim:

**CSS:**

```
@media print {
    #header {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    #content {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
    Cabeçalhos
</div>
<div id="content">
    ... conteúdo das paginas
</div>
```

Fonte: [Print header/footer on all pages (Print Mode) - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356881/print-header-footer-on-all-pages-print-mode)

Comment: Fernando, infelizmente não funcionou

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa, é possível você trocar os dados sensíveis e demonstrar como ficou seu relatório que não funcionou? (Você testou no Firefox né?)

Comment: Na verdade eu testei no IE. Ele simplesmente ignorou a `<div>` continuo como está antes da alteração. Verifiquei o posicionamento das mesmas no html gerado e estava correto, coloquei "!important" no CSS...